# Trying to insert a value in a user initialized array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have to write an array manipulator with 6 functions, which are all called in main. I wrote most of the functions, but the ones I am stuck on is one where the user chooses from a menu to add an element at a specified index, and another function where the user chooses to remove an element. This is the code I have so far for the insertElement function:

```
int main()
// other cases;
       case 5:
            cout << "Enter a value to insert: ";
            cin >> insert;
            cout << "Enter a position to insert the value in: ";
            cin >> pos;
            pos--;
                if (pos < 0 || pos > size)
                {
                    cout << "Invalid Index " << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    size = insertValue(arr, value, pos, size);
                    displayArray(arr, size);
                }
            break;

int insertValue(int arr[], int value, int pos, int size)

if (size == 10)
    cout << "Array full" << endl;
else
{
    int i;
    for (i = size - 1; i >= pos; --i) {
        arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
    }
    arr[i] = value;
}
cout << endl;
return size;
```

I think my function for adding an element is right, but when I run it with array values of 3 4 5, and tell the program to add the number 4 at index 1, it prints 3 3 4, and 5 is left out of the array. how can I make the program print 3 4 4 5?
Thank you for all your help!

Comment: You need to increase size by 1  after insert.

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase size by 1 after insert.

```
int insertValue(int arr[], int value, int pos, int size)
{
    if (size == 10)
        std::cout << "Array full\n";
    else
    {
        int i;
        for (i = size - 1; i >= pos; --i)
        {
            arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
        }
        arr[pos] = value;
        ++size;
    }
    return size;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, it increased the array size, but now when I tell the code to insert 4 into the array of 3 4 5 at index 1 it prints 3 3 4 5 instead of 3 4 4 5. Do you know why the value was decreased?

Comment: I fixed the mistake, but now when I run it it prints a very long number, or a garbage value, then 4 4 5. Is something wrong with my main function?

Comment: @SabinaBhuiyan Try this again.

Answer (score 0):

The size issue looks like you need to increase the size after inserting.

I think you may also have another issue in case 5. You cin a variable named 'insert', but you pass your function a variable named 'value'. I assume that 'value' is a variable for another case, and could cause you issue when inserting.

~Best of luck

Comment: @ Joe I changed it to size = insertValue(arr, insert, pos, size);, but now when I run it it prints 4 4 4 5 instead of 3 4 4 5. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: @SabinaBhuiyan My guess is that it has to do with the way you pre-decrement your counter in insertValue for loop. Try doing arr[pos] = value;

Comment: Also when I try to add the value 3 to the array 1 2 3 at the index 1 it prints 3 2 2 3. I'm very confused, any ideas on how to fix this??? I tried your suggestion and it didn't work.